# Find closest point of labelled area to a point in an image with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to find the closes point to an area in an image with Matlab:

consider this example code:

```
myimg = rgb2gray(imread('tissue.png')); %load grayscale example image of cells
BW=bwareaopen(myimg<150,10); %only look at dark pixels, remove small objects
BW=bwlabel(imfill(BW,'holes')) %fill holes of structures, label structures
figure; 
imagesc(BW); %display image
```

I'd like to find the closest point of the closest structure to a point e.g. [0,0]. My approach so far is to get all centroids of all connected structures, then loop through all of them to find the closest one (inaccurate and inefficient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find a single closest point, you can use `bwdist` with a second output argument. This will give you a matrix which at each point contains the linear index of the closest non-zero point of the input image. You then just need to select the index corresponding to the point you are interested in. The input image to `bwdist` should be binary, so in your case you could try something like

```
% Make the image binary
binaryimage = BW > 0;

% Get the linear indices of the closest points
[~, idx] = bwdist(binaryimage);

% Find the linear index for point (3, 2)
x = 3;
y = 2;
pointindex = sub2ind(size(binaryimage), y, x);

% Find the index of the closet point from the segmentation
closestpointindex = idx(pointindex);

% Get coordinates of the closest point
[yc, xc] = ind2sub(size(binaryimage), closestpointindex);
```

This will give you the coordinates `(xc, yc)` and the matrix index (`closestpointindex`) of the pixel with a non-zero value in the binary image which is closest to the point `(x,y)`, where `x` and `y` are Matlab indices, remembering that Matlab indices start at `1` and rows are first, i.e. `BW(y,x)`.